# dynamically port forward for by passing Internet censorship

Tags: ssh, nohup, socks5

I want to make SSH port forwarding to solve and bypass censorship.
I saw many examples and Youtube but I can't get what I want. Every month I must purchase a new VPS due to an advanced filtering system in Iran. Some companies solved their problems by socks proxy but I couldn't find that solution.

Example,

- Iran IP: 198.51.100.10
- German IP: 198.51.100.20
  Code:

```
nohup ssh -4 -D 198.51.100.10:8080 root@198.51.100.20 &
```

This command in many shapes gives me an error. I would appreciate it if you could help me to grant my network freedom.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How may I do a SSH tunneling?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/539937/how-may-i-do-a-ssh-tunneling)

Comment: Have you read e.g. `man ssh`?

Comment: What errors do you get?