# What's the best way to forward a local port to a port on a remote machine that minimizes latency?

Tags: networking, server, performance, port-forwarding

For this question, assume all computers involved are running the most-recent Ubuntu LTS release (or similar, such as Ubuntu Server).

I have a computer on my LAN. Let's call it "Local Server", and we'll say it has an IP of `192.168.1.2`. I also have a cloud VPS, called "Public Server" Let's also say we have a DNS A record that says that `server.example.com` goes to the public IP address of my VPS. For simplicity's sake, we'll assume there isn't a firewall on it, even though there would be in reality.

I'm going to put a web server onto Local Server:

```bash
$ sudo apt update && sudo apt install nginx
...
$ sudo systemctl start nginx
...
```

From another computer on `192.168.1.0/24`, I'll do `curl 192.168.1.2:80` to ensure it works:

```
$ curl 'http://192.168.1.2:80'
[The HTML for the welcome to NGINX page]
```

It works, great. However, I want to make it so that port 8080 on Public Server (a.k.a. the VPS) is 'mapped' to port 80 on Local Server. I.e., I want a third computer called "Client Machine" to be able to `curl http://server.example.com:8080`, and then the VPS gets that request, passes it back to Local Server, gets the response from Local Server, and gives the response to "Client Machine". But, I want it to appear to Client Machine as if Public Server had just handled the request directly.

There's a few caveats, though:

- The service isn't really a web server, despite me using it as an example. So it actually needs to deal with the traffic - an HTTP reverse-proxy won't work
- Local Server cannot be port-forwarded at all
- Other ports on the cloud VPS *can* be used, for example, Local Server might connect to one for communication between Local Server and the VPS
- Running my app on the VPS directly is not an option here
- I care *first and foremost* about latency for responses - I'm running a game server, so latency is more important than raw throughput

Here's some options that I've found:

- [rathole](https://github.com/rapiz1/rathole)
- SSH port forwarding (`ssh cocomac@server.example.com -R 0.0.0.0:8080:localhost:80`, `GatewayPorts` also needs to be `yes` in `sshd_config`)

What's the best way to do this that minimizes latency as much as possible?

Comment: Probably ["tunneling"](https://askubuntu.com/q/539937) is what you need and not "port forwarding".

Comment: Agreed an SSH tunnel is what you need. I did this recently with exactly your setup. A public VPS running nginx, and a private server at home running mastodon. An SSH tunnel forwarded port 80 on nginx publicly over the tunnel to the mastodon instance inside my firewall. Worked fine for weeks.

Answer (score 0):

Generally answering your general question i.e. "What are my options?" ... You can later choose and ask a new question about one specific method to get a specific detailed answer if you wish.

#### No Firewall/NAT required (*ordered by least latency first*)

- **Domain masking (*AKA "DNS framed forwarding" or "URL frame"*):**

  This will redirect the visitor to an alternate URL that you choose while keeping your domain name in the title/address field ... It depends on your domain name service provider ... However, most service providers have it ... See for example:

  [Examole #1](https://ae.godaddy.com/help/whats-the-difference-between-domain-forwarding-and-masking-32147)

  [Example #2](https://www.site24x7.com/learn/dns-redirects.html)
- **SSH(*or alternatives*) tunneling:**

  This will create a tunnel between a source and a destination machine to send/forward requests from the source to the destination machine and receive replies in the background ... See for example [Secure Shell tunneling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tunneling_protocol#Secure_Shell_tunneling).
- **Remote fetching by means of a local service:**

  This method requires that you configure a service(*can also rely on common services like a script file on a web server*) on a certain port/URL that will process the incoming request, fetch response from the remote machine/URL and display it after processing to the visitor.

#### Firewall/NAT required

- **DNAT(*Destination NAT*):**

  This will forward the request sent to one machine on a certain port to another machine in the background without the visitor noticing or knowing ... Obviously, if the other machine is also behind a Firewall/NAT, popper ordinary port forwarding will be required as well on its end ... See for example [Destination NAT with netfilter (DNAT)](http://linux-ip.net/html/nat-dnat.html).